# Acumatica - Contract REST API - EnterPOReceipt action

Tags: rest, acumatica

I am trying to create a PO Reciept from a Purchase Order using the Contract REST API. I use the following body:

```
{
  "entity": {
      "OrderNbr": {
          "value": "<<PO Number>>"
      }
  }
}
```

The response I get is `202 Accepted`, but it does not look like it created a purchase receipt in Purchase Receipts.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The 202 Status just means that the request was well formulated and was accepted by the system. The request is now currently being processed.

This mostly occurs when the action that you are trying to trigger includes a long running operation.

In order to see the actual result of the action you need to perform a Get operation at the url available in the Location header of the response.

You can find more information here :

https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=91bf9106-062a-47a8-be1f-b48517a54324

Comment: Yes, I understand, but when I GET the url from Location from the response to the first request, it just returns `204 No Content` even though I can't find the receipt created (if it is created). 

I don't think it was created because first, the "new receipt" is not at the top of the list of Purchase Receipts, and second, it is not in the PO History of the Purchase Order.

Comment: The 204 response means that the action was completed successfully. You can see that response code in the link that I have in my answer